# selecting dropdown list and change step attribute of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want when choosed  A option , input value will be 10,20,30 ...
for B option, input value 5,10,15,20
that code didnt work what is wrong

```
<select onchange="changeValue(this);" id="size" name="attribute_size">

    <option selected="selected" value="">choose option…</option>                              
    <option class="active" value="A">A</option>
    <option class="active" value="B">B</option>
</select>

<input min="1" step="1" id="quantity" value="1" title="quantity" class="input-text qty text" size="4" type="number">

function changeValue() {
    var option2 = document.getElementById('size').options[document.getElementById('size').selectedIndex].id;
    if (option2 == "A") {
        document.getElementById('quantity').setAttribute('step', "10");
    }
else  (option2 == "B")
{
        document.getElementById('quantity').setAttribute('step', "5");
    }
}
```

Comment: `options[selectedIndex].id` or ``options[selectedIndex].value` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missed `if` after `else` which was causing console error,

```
else if (option2 == "B")
```

Change the `min` attribute to '0',

```
<input min="0" step="1" id="quantity" value="0" title="quantity" class="input-text qty text" size="4" type="number">
```

And Javascript,

```
function changeValue(that) {
    var option2 =that.options[that.selectedIndex].text;
    var inputElm = document.getElementById('quantity');
    inputElm.value = 0;
    if (option2 == 'A') {
        inputElm.setAttribute('step', '10');
    } else if (option2 == 'B') {
        inputElm.setAttribute('step', '5');
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/msuL0yta/113/)

Also, you can use the `this` onject passed in the parameter when operating on the current object.

Comment: @Süleyman Yelgeç your welcome, you can accept it as an answer if it helped.

Comment: thanks it is works better but i Forgot that, input value will be start from zero  form example 0,5,10,15 ..:( and every changed selected drop value set input value to 0

Comment: @Süleyman Yelgeç Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/msuL0yta/120/

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code. (For example typo in `else if`, wrong method of getting select option value and not using your argument in `changeValue` method)

I corrected them and put them together to working example:

```
<select onchange="changeValue(this);" id="size" name="attribute_size">
    <option selected="selected" value="">choose option...</option>                              
    <option class="active" value="A">A</option>
    <option class="active" value="B">B</option>
</select>

<input min="1" step="1" id="quantity" value="1" title="quantity" class="input-text qty text" size="4" type="number">

<script>
function changeValue(elem) {
    var input = document.getElementById('quantity');

    if (elem.value == "A") {
        input.setAttribute('step', "10");
    }else if (elem.value == "B") {
        input.setAttribute('step', "5");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what are you intended to do with 'input' variable? You have used 'document.getElementById('quantity')' twice instead you can use 'input' variable.

Comment: My intention was not to use `getElementById` multiple times for same element and replace it with `input` but I forgot to change that.
Its fixed now, thanks